Type guard not narrowing union type
Consider the below code:
type UnionType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

const obj = {
    foo: 'huh',
    bar: 'hmm'
}

function func(input: UnionType) {
    if(input in obj) {
        input
    }
}

Playground
input is not being narrowed to 'foo' | 'bar'. Why is that?
Is there a way to make it narrow the union down, without explicitly re-stating the object keys?

Because in operator narrowing works on the right-hand side (narrows obj to members of the union with an input property: https://tsplay.dev/Wke0lN), not the left-hand side.

Thanks @jonrsharpe. I need to narrow input down, in its given form, if it exists as a property on obj. How would you do that?

You want ms/TS#43284 which has not been implemented nor is it likely to be. You can write a user-defined type guard to work around it as shown in the top of that issue. For your example it would look like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes, thank you, that addresses it.

Currently in TypeScript input in obj only acts as a type guard on obj, not on input. There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#43284 asking for it to act as a type guard on input also, but it hasn't been implemented and it's unlikely to be implemented because, as it says in this comment, the consensus is that such behavior would be wrong and interact badly with the existing type guards.
Note that such narrowing has always been a bit suspect, because types in TypeScript are not "sealed" (or "exact" to use terminology from Flow, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#12936). Just because input in obj is true, it doesn't mean that input is one of the known keys of typeof obj. I could change your code to this:
const _obj = {
    foo: 'huh',
    bar: 'hmm',
    baz: 'oops'
}

const obj: { foo: string, bar: string } = _obj; // okay

Which compiles just fine, because the type {foo: string, bar: string} is not "sealed" and does not prohibit other properties. So if TypeScript narrowed the way you wanted it to, then input in obj would narrow input to "foo" | "bar", but clearly it could actually still be "baz".  So such narrowing would be unsafe.
That doesn't mean it should definitely not happen; TypeScript isn't perfectly type safe anyway, and by the same argument it wouldn't be safe to narrow a value o of type {a: string} | {b: string} based on "a" in o, but that narrowing happens today:
const a: { a: string } = { a: "" };
const _b = { b: "", a: 123 };
const b: { b: string } = _b;
const o = Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b;
if ("a" in o) {
    o // narrowed to { a: string }, unsafely
    o.a.toUpperCase() 
}

So soundness isn't the only consideration. Still, until and unless the TS team changes their mind, it doesn't look like the narrowing you want will happen. You'll have to work around it.

The easiest workaround is to write a user-defined type guard function that behaves the way you want input in obj to behave. In microsoft/TypeScript#43284, there's such a function:
const in_ = <K extends string, O extends object>(key: K, object: O):
    key is K & keyof O => key in object;

And now if you replace input in obj with in_(input, obj) you'll see the expected behavior:
function func(input: UnionType) {
    if (in_(input, obj)) {
        input
        //^? (parameter) input: "foo" | "bar"
    } else {
        input
        //^? (parameter) input: "baz"
    }
}

The same caveat about soundness applies, so it's up to you to decide if that matters for your use case.
Playground link to code

Thank you, jcalz. I am working my way through the answer. I struggle understanding the difference between narrowing through assignment for an object vs a primitive value. const obj2: {} = _obj; obj2; //^? const y: string | number = 1; y; //^?
In the object case (x), the left hand side is not narrowed to the right hand side. But for y, it is narrowed to number. Playground: https://tsplay.dev/NaA2nN

I don’t see how that relates directly to this question. For unions, there is assignment narrowing. How does that apply here?

I see. It seems there are two key points here: 1) Narrowing with the in operator only narrows the object, not the property (even if it is a union), and 2) The union is not narrowed because Typescript object types are not sealed. It seems odd that it is allowed to do const obj: { foo: string, bar: string } = _obj when the Excess Property Check prevents this: const obj: { foo: string, bar: string } = { foo: string, bar: string, baz: string }. Do you know why the former assignment is allowed?

Excess property checking only happens when TS thinks it will forget a property entirely. An assignment like const a: {b: string} = {b:"", c:0} is considered an error because the  c property is completely thrown away. But const a = {b:"", c:0}; const d:{b:string}=a is allowed because even though d doesn’t know about c, that information is still available in a. There are other stack overflow q/a about excess property checking and exact types, so you might want to look those up for more information.
